# flutter SkCanvas::Flush execution is too slow

Tags: flutter, performance, optimization

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: TabBarPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TabBarPageState();
  }
}

class TabBarPageState extends State<TabBarPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _tabController; //需要定义一个Controller
  List tabs = ["page 1", "page 2", "page 3", "page 4", "page 5", "page 6"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("TabBarPageState initState");
    _tabController = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    print("TabBarPageState dispose");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("TabBarPageState build");
    return Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(

        controller: _tabController,
        children: getChildWidgets(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        tabs: tabs.map((item) {
          return Container(color: Colors.black,child: Text(item, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),);
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getChildWidgets() {
    return List<Widget>()..addAll([PageWidget("page 1", Colors.red), PageWidget("page 2", Colors.yellow), PageWidget("page 3", Colors.blue),
      PageWidget("page 4", Colors.green), PageWidget("page 5", Colors.deepPurpleAccent), PageWidget("page 6", Colors.tealAccent), ]);
  }


}

class PageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color bgColor;

  PageWidget(this.title, this.bgColor);

  @override
  _PageWidgetState createState() => _PageWidgetState();
}

class _PageWidgetState extends State<PageWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("_PageWidgetState initState ${widget.title}");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    print("_PageWidgetState dispose ${widget.title}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("_PageWidgetState build ${widget.title}");
    super.build(context);
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        color: widget.bgColor,
        child: "page 2" != widget.title ? Text(widget.title) : RawMaterialButton(child: Text(widget.title), onPressed: (){ Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SecondPageWidget("测试", Colors.deepOrangeAccent)));},),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}


class SecondPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color bgColor;

  SecondPageWidget(this.title, this.bgColor);

  @override
  _SecondPageWidgetState createState() => _SecondPageWidgetState();
}

class _SecondPageWidgetState extends State<SecondPageWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("SecondPageWidget ${widget.title} build");
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        color: widget.bgColor,
        child: Text(widget.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A very simple test, click on the tab on the bottomNavigationBar to switch the page in TabBarView, but it cannot reach 60FPS from the devTools, and the time-consuming is mainly reflected in the SkCanvas::Flush operation on the Raster thread 。

Can you please tell me how to optimize the speed ？

Jump from page 1 to page 2, whether it has a lot to do with RawMaterialButton, then how to optimize ？

```
Target Platform: android

Target OS version/browser: android 9

Devices: Redmi Note 5

D:\Users\yl4111>flutter doctor
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...                      17.1s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.30], locale zh-CN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```